# How to resolve strict warning in a shared host?

Tags: php, drupal

I moved my site which is developed with drupal cms to a new windows host with php 5.4.14 but I encounter following error. how to resolve it?

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically....
```

I am not a php developer so I'm new to it.
I have read many blogs and they offered some patches. But I don't know how to use the patch.
Please help me.

**complete Error:**

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in D:\HostingSpaces\Roodmajan\roodmajan.com\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\views\views.module on line 903.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_field::query() should be compatible with views_handler::query($group_by = false) in D:\HostingSpaces\Roodmajan\roodmajan.com\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc on line 90.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with views_handler::options_validate($form, &$form_state) in D:\HostingSpaces\Roodmajan\roodmajan.com\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc on line 90.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::query() should be compatible with views_handler::query($group_by = false) in D:\HostingSpaces\Roodmajan\roodmajan.com\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc on line 90.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_query::init() should be compatible with views_plugin::init(&$view, &$display) in D:\HostingSpaces\Roodmajan\roodmajan.com\wwwroot\sites\all\modules\views\includes\handlers.inc on line 90
```

Comment: Need to see the source code that generates this warning. Show where `load()` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can hide *strict warnings* with the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

With drupal you have 2 options:

1. you can disable all on-screen warnings by going to **Administer > Site configuration > Error reporting**, then choose **Write errors to the log**
2. Use the [Disable Messages](https://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module, after install browse to **admin/settings/disable-messages** and make sure "Enable filtering" is checked, then put this in the "Messages to be disabled:"
   field: **strict .*.**